# How to call php function "oninput" just like javascript function is called?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

This code was working with php for "submit" button but I want it on runtime. So I want to use "oninput" but it is javascript function. What is possible alternate?

```
<?php
    $new_name = "";
    function my_php_function()
    {   
        echo "Hello {$_POST['user_name']}";
        $new_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    }
    ?>

    <html>

    <form action="" method="post">
        Name:  <input type="text" name="user_name" oninput="my_php_function()" /><br />
        new_name:  <input type="text" name="new_name" value="<?php echo $new_name; ?>"/>  
    </form>

    </html>
```

Comment: Php has no functions `oninput` and `onsubmit`. They are Javascript (clientside) and send data to the server. PHP recieves that data, processes it and sends something back (or not). The only way to aceive what you want is constantly sending data to the server, process it and send it back. Take a look at AJAX.

Comment: can you tell me how?

Comment: the nearest you could get would be to use ajax to send the request to the php script. PHP runs on the server and knows nothing of the browser or what is going on it it event wise

Answer (score 0):

An example of using an ajax function bound to the `oninput` event to call your php function.

```
<?php
    $new_name='';

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        function my_php_function( $name ){
            $name = !empty( $_POST['user_name'] ) ? $_POST['user_name'] : $name;
            return $name;
        }
        exit( my_php_function( &$new_name ) );
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script>
            /* a re-usable ajax function */
            function ajax( url, params, callback ){
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( this.readyState==4 && this.status==200 ) callback.call( this, xhr.response );
                };

                var payload=[];
                for( var n in params )payload.push( n+'='+params[n] );
                payload=payload.join('&');

                xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( payload );
            }

            /* event handler to send ajax request */
            function call_my_php_function( event ){
                ajax.call( this, location.href, { user_name:event.target.value }, function(r){
                    document.querySelector('input[name="new_name"]').value=r;
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <form method='post'>
        Name:  <input type='text' name='user_name' oninput='call_my_php_function( event )' /><br />
        new_name:  <input type='text' name='new_name' value='<?php echo $new_name; ?>'/>  
    </form>
</html>
```